# Django mysql query

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I am new to django and I have difficulty in constructing django query.
Can anyone please help me to construct this query into django query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT mt.ID_Number 
FROM measurement_test mt 
WHERE mt.Start_Date IN('2012-02-15','2012-06-14') 
AND mt.ID_Number != ''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming "measurement_test" is the object the models the relevant table.

```
measurement_test.objects.values_list(ID_Number).filter(Start_Date__in=('2012-02-15','2012-06-14')).exclude(ID_Number='').distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following,

```
measurement_test.objects.filter(~Q(ID_Number=''), Start_Date__in=['2012-02-15','2012-06-14']).values('ID_Number').distinct()
```

Comment: Don't forget the `distinct()` method https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Comment: This is not a valid Django query. You can't use `!=` in filter calls.